# My sister doesn't know whether tomorrow can be a holiday for her

Tags: tense, exam-questions

> My sister doesn't know **whether tomorrow can be a holiday for her.**

This is a sentence improvement question asked in my exam. Which of the below given two options is the correct answer ?

A) My sister doesn't know whether tomorrow will be a holiday for her.

B) My sister doesn't know whether tomorrow is a holiday for her.

For me both sentences convey same meaning but I can't figure which one to choose as answer.

Comment: I'd stick to B.

Comment: @SovereignSun My book too has B as answer but I think the explanation given is wrong, it says 'will' is not appropriate with 'whether' but I can find many sentences on google with will and whether used together .

Comment: @user212388 What's the name of the book. I suggest you add it in your question so that future learners know that the book is misleading.

Answer (score 11):

This is a  poor question since all of the verbs are grammatical and could be used according to the context: **can, will, is**. It's one of those questions where you have to shrink your skull down so it fits into the mindset of the examiner. You have to ask yourself, which context is the most "usual".

> My sister doesn't know if tomorrow can be a holiday for her.

She may not be able to elect to take the day off. She may have to work even if the organization regards the day as a holiday.

> My sister doesn't know if tomorrow will be a holiday for her.

Tomorrow may be a holiday for the organization, but she may have to work nonetheless. Perhaps she is waiting to hear from her boss in this regard.

> My sister doesn't know if tomorrow is a holiday for her.

She doesn't know whether the organization she works at treats tomorrow as a holiday.

Comment: I'd still stick to  "**My sister doesn't know if tomorrow is a holiday for her.**"

Comment: Good to know. But why?

Comment: Hard to say, but something's telling me that "**is**" is most appropriate here.

Comment: @SovereignSun and TRomano, the question uses 'whether', not 'if'.

Comment: @user178049 No big difference.

Comment: @SovereignSun In this case, yes, there is no big difference. But only *if* (not 'whether') can be used in a conditional sentence and it usually cannot be used with—as you mentioned—'will' in such a situation. So it can be confusing. See [this](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1912)

Comment: I don't know where you found the *rule* that **will** cannot be used with **if** but native speakers routinely use this construction and have been doing so for 200 years at least. And **whether** has no impact on whether we can choose **will**, **can**, or **is** there.  I don't think any contemporary linguist would insist on using **whether** in the sentences I've supplied as examples.

Comment: Here you will find many attestations: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22does%20not%20know%20if%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @SovereignSun "I'd still stick to..." That's fine, you can stick (or not) to anything you want, but your personal choice doesn't answer the OP's question (unless you also believe that "whatever I say three times is true", of course).

Comment: @SovereignSun: Replace "if" with "whether". There is, actually, a "big difference", for those who care about grammar.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I'm a "contemporary linguist" and I certainly would insist upon **whether** there. I certainly do not disagree that the trend of abusing **if**  is worsening; but this is disheartening! (It seems particularly prevalent in the North American variants of English)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: The abuse began before you were born. And I don't think it is a trait of North American English.  It's well attested in BrE. https://books.google.com/books?id=UvtFax6wXiEC&pg=PP35&dq=%22know+if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0zs_omebUAhUBaz4KHeGmBskQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=%22know%20if%22&f=false

Comment: @SovereignSun I think you've got this wrong.  This post  explains that "will be" and "is" have slightly different meanings here.  And the meaning of "will be" here is closer to the meaning of the original "can be".  So as an improvement of the original sentence, "will be" is the correct answer.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I'm well aware that it's a long-standing abuse. Yet it is abuse just the same, and one utilised with contemporaneously increasing frequency. Your citation is interesting as it is barely even from what we now call "English"; many aspects of _that_ language differ from what we'd expect to use at any time within the last 200 or 300 years.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Maybe, but somehow "**is**" sounds like the most proper way of saying it.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit:   I show you something that's been going on since Shakespeare's day, and you refer to it as *abuse* rather than *use*?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on when the holiday is/was declared.

If the holiday status was set prior to the time she spoke, you can use *is* (although *will* is also often used in the same context). The holiday-status of the day isn't in question; she just doesn't know what that status is.

- If a federal holiday falls on a Saturday, the preceding Friday **is** a holiday.
  [- officeholidays.com](http://www.officeholidays.com/countries/usa/index.php) (emphasis, mine)

If the holiday status is uncertain at the time she spoke, use *will*.

- Often the uncertainty does not matter and you will be able to proceed as if tomorrow **will** be just like today
  [- Dennis V Lindley](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=z0ArJ_CDnssC&pg=PA7&dq=%22if%20tomorrow%20will%20be%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi61fLd7OXUAhUCebwKHYi3DW4Q6AEISzAH) (emphasis, mine)
- If you are working in Washington on this day (even if you normally are assigned elsewhere), it **will** be a holiday. If you are on travel elsewhere, it **will** not.
  [- US Dept of Commerce](http://hr.commerce.gov/Employees/Leave/DEV01_005944) (emphasis, mine; the uncertainty stems from not knowing the location)

*Will* can also denote certainty, such as when one is declaring a holiday, or declaring *that* a particular day is a holiday. The *Washington* example above can be argued to fit this interpretation if the quote is taken as an authoritative statement. In any case, this doesn't apply to your example since she "doesn't know".

- Tomorrow, Washington's Birthday, **will** be a holiday in all departments of the University.
  [- The Harvard Crimson](http://www.thecrimson.com/article/1918/2/21/tomorrow-will-be-a-holiday-in/) (emphasis, mine)

Use *can be* if there is an element of choice about the day's holiday status.

- Any Day **Can Be** a Holiday
  [- Huffpost](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/marina-sbrochi/any-day-can-be-a-holiday_b_4257797.html) (emphasis, mine)

So all three variants are possible. Since the original has an element of uncertainty, the *will* version is arguably closer to the intent than the *is* version, though the form of uncertainty is somewhat different.